# Construct class from superclass instance

Tags: inheritance, constructor, python-3.x, pygobject

So you have some function, say `Gtk.Builder.get_object()`, which returns some widget. In our case a `Gtk.Window()`.

I have a subclass of `Gtk.Window()` which adds some signal handlers.

```
class Window(Gtk.Window):
```

Is it possible to use the widget returned by `Gtk.Builder.get_object()` to construct `Window()`? I think it should be using `__new__()` or something, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Can you write to the `__class__` attribute of the `Gtk.Window` instance you're getting?

Comment: @Blckknght Is that safe? I made a quick test where I set `window.__class__ = cls` in `__new__()`. I seem to be able to call methods from the subclass doing this, but `__init__` still isn't run. According to my interpretation of the docs it should, so IDK.

Comment: It should be safe as long as the class you're setting is a subclass of the instance's previous class. I'm not sure why it wouldn't call `__init__` if you're returning the modified instance from `__new__`. I'm going to write the suggestion up as an answer, but feel free not to accept it until we can figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using `__new__` is exactly what you want to be doing. If you can set the `__class__` attribute of the superclass instance you're getting to the subclass, you should be all set.

Here's what I think you need:

```
class Window(Gtk.Window):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        self = Gtk.Builder.get_object()
        self.__class__ = cls
        return self
```

Python should detect that the value that was created by `__new__` is an instance of the class (thanks to the `__class__` value), then it will call `__init__` and other methods as appropriate.

Comment: @ABP - This should work. In CPython, you can safely reassign `__class__` for instances of heap types that have a compatible memory layout, which is checked at runtime. If `__init__` doesn't run, the metaclass `__call__` method must be overridden.

Comment: Ok, this does seems to work, actually. I defined new like `def __new__(cls, data_dir)` and created the object like `Window.__new__(Window, '..')`, but this must be incorrect.

Comment: I just checked, and `gobject.GObjectMeta` doesn't override `type.__call__`.